# session verify isn't working after login

Tags: php, session

I've built a php login that verifies the user and redirects then to landing.php if successful. Otherwise, the login error is given to the user. Once on landing.php, I am trying to check that $_SESSION exists. If it does, then use a piece of it. If it doesn't it should redirect the user to the login page. However, if I directly type the landing.php url in the browser to skip the login, the page never redirects even though the $_SESSION is empty. Please advise to the best way to check the session.

MY CODE:

landing.php: (PHP Script)

```
<?php
session_start();

  include('inc.php');

  if (!(session_id())) {

    header("Location: ['url']/index.php"); /*url not displayed for security*/

  } else {
    $welcome = "Welcome ".$_SESSION['userinfo']['firstname'];
  }

?>
```

login.php: (Where session is created)

```
<?php
session_start();

include("inc.php");


if ((isset($_POST['username'])) and (isset($_POST['password']))) {

    $login = $_POST['username'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];

} else {
    //echo json_encode("Credentials did not save. Please try again.");
    echo "Credentials did not save. Please try again.";
}


$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);


if ($conn->connect_errno) {
    //echo json_encode("There was a problem connecting to MySQL: (" . $conn->connect_errno . ") " . $conn->connect_error);
    echo "There was a problem connecting to MySQL: (" . $conn->connect_errno . ") " . $conn->connect_error;
    //echo json_encode("There was a problem connecting to MySQL.");
}


$sql = "SELECT * FROM sched_users WHERE login = ? ORDER BY login LIMIT 1";

if (!($sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM sched_users WHERE login = ? ORDER BY login LIMIT 1"))) {
    //echo json_encode("Prepare failed: (" . $conn->errno . ") " . $conn->error);
    echo "Prepare failed: (" . $conn->errno . ") " . $conn->error;
    //echo json_encode("Prepare failed.");
}


if (!($sql->bind_param("s", $login))) {
    //echo json_encode("Binding parameters failed: (" . $sql->errno . ") " . $sql->error);
    echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $sql->errno . ") " . $sql->error;
    //echo json_encode("Binding parameters failed.");
}


if (!$sql->execute()) {
    //echo json_encode("Execute failed: (" . $sql->errno . ") " . $sql->error);
    echo "Execute failed: (" . $sql->errno . ") " . $sql->error;
    //echo json_encode("Execute failed.");
}


$res = $sql->get_result();


if ($res->num_rows === 0) {

    //echo json_encode("No user record found.");
    echo "No user record found.";

} else if (!(($res->num_rows === 1) or ($res->num_rows === 0))) {

    //echo json_encode("Too many results returned.");
    echo "Too many results returned.";

} else {

    $row = $res->fetch_array();

    $hash = $row['password'];

    if (password_verify($pass, $hash)) {

        /*
        $session = true;
        echo json_encode($session);
        */

        $_SESSION['userinfo']['firstname'] = $row['firstname'];
        $_SESSION['userinfo']['lastname'] = $row['lastname'];
        $_SESSION['userinfo']['email'] = $row['email'];
        $_SESSION['userinfo']['phone'] = $row['phone'];
        $_SESSION['userinfo']['company'] = $row['company'];
        $_SESSION['userinfo']['department'] = $row['department'];
        $_SESSION['userinfo']['admin'] = $row['admin'];
        $_SESSION['userinfo']['statusflag'] = $row['statusflag'];
        $_SESSION['userinfo']['revoked'] = $row['revoked'];


        header("location: [url]/landing.php");/*url not displayed for security*/

    } else {
        //$session = false;
        //echo json_encode($session);
        //echo json_encode("The username or password does not match. Please try again.");
        echo "The username or password does not match. Please try again.";
    }

}


$sql->close();
$conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: session_id() will always return if session is start, you need to check for `isset($_SESSION['userinfo'])`

Comment: The same problem with this is that now, its not finding the session info at all after login so its redirecting back to the login page. But when I don't have the criteria set to check if the session exists, it can bring over some of the session info and display a name for the user. Wouldn't that mean the session is set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
session_start();
...
if (!(session_id())) {
```

As soon as you start your session, you will have a session ID so the condition `!(session_id()` will always be false.

You should check for the content of the session instead, for example:

```
if (!array_key_exists('userinfo', $_SESSION)) {
    ...
```

Comment: The problem with this is that now, its not finding the session info at all after login so its redirecting back to the login page. But when I don't have the criteria set to check if the session exists, it can bring over some of the session info and display a name for the user. Wouldn't that mean the session is set?

Comment: I figured out the issue was caused by using the full URL in my successful login redirect script. This blocked the session from carrying over. After shortening the URL to simply say header('location: landing.php') everything worked as it should. Thank you!